# Histogramm Binning Two Data Sets With Reference To Each Other

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, binning

I have two lists of equal length. Each item in one list corresponds to the same index in the other list.
I have histogrammed one of the two lists:

```
xnums, xbins = np.histogram(x)
```

What I need is a quick way to bin the corresponding data accordingly, i.e. bin the data in y in correspondence with how x has been binned.
I have tried:

```
ybins = []    

for i in range(len(xnums)):
     yi = []
         for j in range(len(y)):
             if x[j] >= xbins[i] and x[j] < xbins[i+1]:
                 yi.append(y[j])
             elif i == len(xnums) and x[j] == max(x):
                 yi.append(y[j])
     ybins.append(yi)
```

but this is slow, and for some reason it misses out some values.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then you want to use `xbins` as `ybins`, and find the corresponding `ynums` (i.e. the counts).

You want [`np.digitize()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html). Give it `y` and `xbins` and it will give you the indices of the bins that `y`'s elements fall into.

Then you can use [`np.bincount()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to count everything and get `ynums`.

```
y_digitized = np.digitize(y, xbins)
ynums = np.bincount(y_digitized)
```